# Can't link/include C library 'krb5.h', 'krb5', aborting

Tags: perl, cpan

I am installing a LAMP stack. (Linux Apache MySQL, Perl).

I am attempting to install the perl module authen::krb5 on Ubuntu.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Authen::Krb5

I have tried via CPAN and CPANM with commands:

```
cpanm Authen::Krb5

perl -MCPAN -e shell install Authen::Krb5
```

I have also tried installing the module manually via these instructions:

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-install-perl-modules-manually-and-using-cpan-command/

but I always receive the error *Can't link/include C library 'krb5.h', 'krb5', aborting.*

Answer (score 1):

If this is for your system Perl, I suggest you install the module by installing the `libauthen-krb5-perl` system package rather than using CPAN.

```sh
sudo apt-get install libauthen-krb5-perl
```

Read on if you want to install it using `cpan`/`cpanm` (perhaps because it's for  a `perl` other than the system `perl`).

---

The module apparently uses a C library. It obviously needs the library. But to compile a module that uses the library, the library's headers are also needed. You appear to be missing both.

I'm not going to cover installing the library from source.

When installing the library using a package manager, it's common for the header files to be split out into a separate package (commonly named "dev" or "devel") since they aren't needed to use the library. On Ubuntu, I suspect that the `libkrb5-3` package provides the library, and that the `libkrb5-dev` package provides the headers.

```sh
sudo apt-get install libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev
```

Then, Authen::Krb5's installer should work.

```sh
cpan Authen::Krb5
```

Or if installing for the system `perl`,

```sh
sudo cpan Authen::Krb5
```

Comment: Thank you @ikegami! after installing these packages and running cpanm Authen::Krb5 as the root user I successfully installed the module